# Обфускатор Java байт-кода, способный не просто менять имена на "a.a.b", а именно делать байт-код недекомпилируемым

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, обфускация

Хотелось бы чтобы код именно невозможно было декомпилировать, то есть декомпилятор при проходе по методу давал экскепшн, а еще лучше терял из виду какой-то блок кода и вроде бы выдавал нормальный результат, но нужного блока в нем не было. В то же время, код естественно должен быть валидным, не вызывать VerifyError.

Я думаю, что такое возможно, ведь в Java гораздо меньше свободы, чем в ее байт-коде, поэтому не любой байт-код можно записать в виде кода Java.

Например, что, если в байт-коде получится вот так:

```
switch (test) {
case aaaa:
  break;
  :foo  <---------
  goto :foo2; ---|------
case bbbb:       |     |
  goto :foo; ----|     |
  break;               |
case cccc:             |
  break;               |
  :foo2  <--------------
  hidden_code();
}
```

Или вообще так:

```
switch (test) {
case aaaa:
  break;
  :foo3  <---------------
  hidden_code();        |
case bbbb:              |
  goto :foo -----|      |
  break;         |      |
case cccc:       |      |
  break;         |      |
  :foo  <---------      |
  goto :foo2 --------|  |
}                    |  |
                     |  |
switch (test2) {     |  |
case aaaa:           |  |
  break;             |  |
case bbbb:           |  |
  break;             |  |
case cccc:           |  |
  break;             |  |
  :foo2  <------------  |
  goto :foo3 -----------|
}
```

Ведь в Java нет goto, он есть только в опкодах JVM или DEX, и как такой байт-код можно декомпилировать?

Важная деталь: if != switch в байт-коде Java.

Некоторые декомпиляторы просто не станут смотреть дальше break, все равно непонятно куда девать этот блок.

А уж try-catch вообще прикольная штука.

В общем, не составляет большого труда придумать вот такие частные случаи, когда испытания подтверждают, что код валиден с точки зрения Dalvik или JVM, но невалиден для многих декомпиляторов.

Так вот есть ли обфускатор, который автоматически вставляет в любой байт-код такие конструкции, чтобы он не декомпилировался?

Answer (score 8):

SABLE описывает подобные подходы к обфускации в публикации о [JBCO](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/JBCO/index.html). [Ссылка на публикацию](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/publications/techreports/sable-tr-2006-5.pdf) (PDF, ~195KB).

> **6.7 Goto Instruction Augmentation (GIA)**
>   Java bytecode does have a goto instruction because it is necessary
>   for simulating higher-level constructs such as loops. Therefore it is possible to insert an explicit goto within the bytecode. *While it is very easily reversed using control flow graph analysis it can still cause many simple decompilers to fail.*

Также описывается ряд приемов, которые используют разницу между Java и байткодом в вызове конструкторов, switch и try/catch.

В принципе, большинство обфускаторов Java производят байткод, который не полностью соответствует корректному коду. Даже при простом переименовании методов, возникают случаи когда метод переопределяется с разными возвращаемыми типами.

Усиление безопасности от использования таких приемов имеет ограничения:

1. Байткод остается в открытом виде. Даже если простой декомпилятор не справится с задачей, по инструкциям JVM можно отследить логику. Для большинства приложений достаточно рассмотреть ключевые классы/методы.
2. Декомпиляторы (например, [Dava](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/dava/) от выше упомянутого SABLE) применяют анализ порядка выполнения и автоматизируют декомпиляцию.
3. Стандартные классы не обфусцируются.

При этом влияние модификаций байткода на производительность сложно оценить/предсказать.

Подробный обзор подходов к защите Java-кода в статье [Protect Your Java Code — Through Obfuscators And Beyond](https://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-obfuscators.html)

Comment: По инструкциям ассемблера совсем не просто что-то отследить, для более-менее крупного кода невозможно удержать все в уме, нужно понимать как работают алгоритмы парсера, и с помощью бумаги и карандаша имитировать парсер, остальное неэффективно.. А если наделать много таких конструкций? Надо еще сделать несколько "рандомных путей", то есть от запуска к запуску "путь" будет через разные ветви, то код не только будет большим, но и отладка затруднена.

Comment: Насчет стандартных классов - здесь загвоздка любой обфускации, то есть опытный исследователь, например, в области malware, просто поставит точки останова на классы вроде java.net.*, и тем самым увидит что вызывается и с какими параметрами. Здесь уже другие средства нужны, вроде MSHookFunction, в идеале вообще скопировать верхние функции сокетов вроде recv, чтобы даже хук на них не помог, и остался либо сниффинг (опять свои минусы), либо копать уже ОС и то, что скопировали...

Comment: @Almik согласен, но байткод — не ассемблер и читается лучше. В принципе, в блоге Эксельсиора как вариант рассматривается компиляция Java напрямую в нативный код.

Comment: @Almik подход звучит разумно, но, во-первых, он непредсказуемо влияет на поведение/производительность кода (недопустимо для массовых обфускаторов), во-вторых, нужно проверить насколько  справляются с такими конструкциями анализаторы кода.

Comment: а также на как можно большем числе платформ протестировать на предмет верификации самой VMой.

Comment: Ссылка SABLE не очень впечатлила - материал староват, про SourceAgain я вообще услышал впервые, пошел искать, но когда нашел про поддержку JDK 1.2 и 1.3 - стало ясно, что правильно делал что не слышал.

Comment: @Almik свежее ничего не нашел :) Впрочем, аргументы против изменений структуры кода при обфускации с тех пор не изменились. По поводу анализаторов можете посмотреть на [Soot](https://sable.github.io/soot/) он вроде бы обновляется (сам про него ничего не могу сказать, к сожалению)